# Delete numerical lines on a CSV (Scripting)

Tags: parsing, vbscript

I´m doing a script which connects to a web service and generate a txt file with stock data. After, it moves and renames that file. After a WP site with tablepress plugin imports that txt file each 15 minutes.
The problem is we need to clear quite lines before wp import takes place.
Un-modded Txt file shows like this:

```
122210099014
PTA200/234
202002800003
902002890008
20PHH4109/88/SC
211301487560
22PFL2807H/12/SC
242201500511
```

And should be converted to:

```
20PHH4109/88/SC
22PFL2807H/12/SC
```

To delete the **PTA** lines I use this:

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFS.OpenTextFile("Z:\COMUNIDAD\TP-VISION\Script\Stock\Stock.txt")
Set objFS1 = objFS.CreateTextFile("Z:\COMUNIDAD\TP-VISION\Script\Stock\Editedwp.txt",true)
objFS1.close
set objTextFile2 = objFS.OpenTextFile("Z:\COMUNIDAD\TP-VISION\Script\Stock\ParsedWP.txt",8)
strFile = "Z:\COMUNIDAD\TP-VISION\Script\Stock\Editedwp.txt"

Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
strLine = objTextFile.ReadLine
If InStr(strLine,"PTA")> 0 Then
    strLine = Replace(strLine,"DeleteMe",1)
  Else
objTextFile2.writeline strLine
End If

Loop

set objTextFile = nothing
set objTextFile2 = nothing

objFS.copyFile "Z:\COMUNIDAD\TP-VISION\Script\Stock\EditedWP.txt", "Z:\COMUNIDAD\TP-VISION\Script\Stock\Stock.txt", true
objfs.DeleteFile "Z:\COMUNIDAD\TP-VISION\Script\Stock\EditedWP.txt"

set objfs = nothing
set objfs1 = nothing
```

That´s let me delete some alphanumerical lines which I don´t need.
**But how to clear a line with only numerical content on the first column?**
Thanks´s a lot!

...I was thinking about it and now I see that deleting every line with minus than 13 characters, will do the job either. So...Can this VBA works or be converted to vbs

```
Sub DelRows()
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = LR To 1 Step -1
If Len(Range("A" & i).Value) < 8 Then Rows(i).Delete
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: OK, so... what's your question? This isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

Independent of the language you are trying to do this, you might want to use this regex:

```
/^[0-9]+$/
```

Try to match this regular expression to every line. If it matches, delete the line.

The regex tests if there are merely digits in a line.

Comment: Hi! Finally I could modify that txt with some scripts, but now I´m stuck on the last mod I need to do. Here´s the code:

Comment: FOR /f "tokens=1,3 delims=_" %A in (STOCK.txt) do @echo %A %B>> WEB.txT

Comment: That´s working perfectly when I execute it on CMD, But running the same instruction within a vbs script returns the error: "Se esperaba un modificador" / "EXPECTED A MODIFIER". Why it´s failing? I need to add anything? Thanks